# Laravel sync throws integrity exception even if extist

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to link all my `TicketMethod` objects to all the `Event` objects:

```
foreach (Event::all() as $event) {
   $event->ticketMethods()->attach([1, 2]);
}
```

The 1 and 2 are the only ids in the db for `TicketMethod`.

In my `Event` I have the following code:

```
public function ticketMethods()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\TicketMethod', 'event_ticket_methods');
}
```

Exception:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update   
  a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tickets`.`event_ticket_method  
  s`, CONSTRAINT `event_ticket_methods_event_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`event_  
  id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `event  
  _ticket_methods` (`event_id`, `ticket_method_id`) values (@/Y�� ���ʫB{�1�,  
   1), (@/Y�� ���ʫB{�1�, 2))
```

The event_id fields are in binary format, which causes the question marks.

I don't get the error, as the event exists as I just retrieved them...

Comment: I think there is a problem in the event id add var_dump to see what's wrong `foreach (Event::all() as $event) {
   var_dump( $event->id);
   $event->ticketMethods()->attach([1, 2]);
}`

Comment: What is the woutput ??

Comment: `string(16) "@/Y�� ���ʫB{�1�"`

Comment: This is the probelm !! why an event in your database have an id like that ??

Comment: It's binary so PHP doesn't format it well. In all other related tables this doesn't cause issues. I don't get why this doesn't work.

Comment: Ok how did you set it's values ?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/alsofronie/eloquent-uuid to generate the ids

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155605/discussion-between-maraboc-and-user2810895).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up by checking all my migrations. The `event_id` column got a different length than the `id` field in the events table.

Comment: Did you have a pivot table in migrations ?

Comment: Yes I do. The pivot table caused the issue as the binary field had a length of 255 instead of 16.